# Cannot reference @types definitions in a global d.ts?

Tags: typescript

Got a global/ambient `d.ts` file in my project like so:

```
/// <reference types="moment" />

declare interface SomeSharedInternalType {
    date: moment.Moment;
}
```

However, the compiler complains

> Cannot find namespace 'moment'

Obviously, I cannot use `import` for this because these declarations have to stay ambient, so how do I reference these type definitions?

Answer (score 1):

```
import * as moment from 'moment'
```

will only import type definitions so remains ambient - it will not compile any of the moment JS

**EDIT** Slightly misread the question here, so for clarity, this is true for ambiently pulling in defs into a TS project (ambient here meaning it will allow you to use types, without any of the referenced module being emmitted in the compiled JS) - however, it does not keep the `.d.ts` file ambient (ambient here meaning that the types declared within do not need to imported by modules that use them, essentially making them global types, the file itself being included in project via `tsconfig.json` configuration)

Comment: No, it will turn the entire `d.ts` file into a "module" declaration, which means it must also be imported when used by other `.ts` files. I want it to stay ambient/global. I.e. any `import` or `export` statement in a `d.ts` file puts that entire file in a namespace.

Comment: Apologies, I mistook you wanted to pull in the moment types ambiently, but actually you want the def file itself to stay ambient. TS has so many confusing usages for that word! In that case I don't think its possible then, as the moment types defs need to be assigned as they don't declare a global `moment`. As this stands the reference would be pulled in but the exported namespace having not been assigned nor declared as a global would make it remain inaccessible to your own defs